# What is inside my ruby array?

Tags: ruby

So I have an Array filled of what exactly?

```
myArray = [ #<Follower id: 1, username: "Prep Bootstrap", imageurl: "http://pbs.twimg.com//profile_images/2825468445/2a4...", user_id: "thefonso", follower_id: "2397558816", created_at: "2014-05-21 15:29:03", updated_at: "2014-05-21 15:29:03">, #<Follower id: 2, username: "JAVA Developer", imageurl: "http://pbs.twimg.com//profile_images/2825468445/2a4...", user_id: "thefonso", follower_id: "2352382640", created_at: "2014-05-21 15:29:05", updated_at: "2014-05-21 15:29:05">,
```

Follower id: 3, username: "JAVA Developer two", imageurl: "http://pbs.twimg.com//profile_images/2825468445/2a4...", user_id: "thefonso", follower_id: "2352382641", created_at: "2014-05-21 17:29:05", updated_at: "2014-05-21 17:29:05"> ]

Now I have many more of these inside this array with consecutive ids, etc..I'm confused by the #< >, is this an array of hashes? What am I looking at exactly? What is this an array of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `ActiveRecord`'s `Followers` class instances. Plus, it looks like you named your model improperly (with Rails practices, it should be named `Follower`).

Comment: You are correct. And I'm being naughty in regard to how I'm naming my model intentionally. It fits better in my brain to think of it as a table containing my followers :)

Comment: @thefonso the table is actually named `followers` in Rails convention, but the model name should be singular. You think of one `Follower` not `Followers`, right? Plus, it would cause problems if you want to describe associations, for example. I strongy advice you to follow convention.

Answer (score 1):

Get the class of one of the objects and you'll know it

```
puts myArray[0].class
```